# Numbers of lines in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I want to ask you if I can make line numbers like in the beta version on this screen: 
[image]

They are slightly different from those in the final version, but I think those in beta version look better. It's not a big deal but I'm interested if there's a solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> All Languages: Line numbers

Answer (score 2):

Tools, Options, Text Editor, *(Your Language)*, Line Numbers.

**EDIT**: Your question is extremely unclear.
You may be looking for   Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors, Line Numbers.

Comment: yes, i know hhow to enable them, but they're different from those on the screenshot. is it possible to look like them or they're just for the beta version ? :)

Comment: @Rock: What are you talking about?

Comment: @SLaks I'm talking about the way numbers of lines are situated on the page where you write projects. On the screenshot they are like separate column in gray and their color is different from the final version where the gray column is way smaller and the numbers are situated on the white sheet. I hope you understood me. Generally i want to ask is there a way i can change the style the numbers are shown.

Comment: @Rock: You can change the coloring in Options, Fonts and Colors.

Comment: @SLaks, thank you very much, that was the thing i was looking for.